# How to write test for this put method

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, junit5, rest

I have a put method, which takes an "Accept" header with value "application/json", and a requestBody class, and returns a ResponseEntity class. Can anyone tell me how to write tests for this method

This is my put api

```
 public ResponseEntity<String> registerUserUsingPUT(@Parameter(in = ParameterIn.DEFAULT, description = "", schema=@Schema()) @Valid @RequestBody UserInput body) {
        String accept = request.getHeader("Accept");
        if (accept != null && accept.contains("application/json")) {
            UserInfo user = userInfoService.getByEmail(body.getEmail());
            if(user==null) {
                user = new UserInfo();
                
                String email = body.getEmail();
                if(email.matches("^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+.[a-z]{2,4}$")) user.setEmail(email);
                
                user.setFirstName(body.getFirstName());
                user.setLastName(body.getLastName());
                user.setPassword(body.getUserPassword());
                user.setRole(roleService.findRoleByType("Customer"));
                
                if(body.getPhoneNo().length()==10) user.setPhoneNumber(body.getPhoneNo());
                else return new ResponseEntity<String>("Incorrect Phone number",HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
                
                user.setPoints(0);
                user.setStatus("Active");
                user.setWalletBalance(0);
                
                AddressDetails address = new AddressDetails();
                address.setAddress(body.getAddress());
                
                String pincode = body.getPinCode();
                if(pincode.matches("^[0-9]{1,6}$")) address.setPincode(pincode);
                
                address.setUser(user);
                
                userInfoService.register(user);
                addressDetailsDao.save(address);
                return new ResponseEntity<String>("Registered",HttpStatus.OK);
            }
            else {
                return new ResponseEntity<String>("User Already Exists",HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);    
            }
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED);
```

Comment: Please clarify your question: What is your problem with the test? What have you tried. As far as I can see, it's just a standard method, so standard unit test techniques apply.

Comment: @KathrinGeilmann, I have updated the questions. Do I need to provide service and dao classes?

Comment: Yes, otherwise you get NPEs if you call methods on them. Or more precisly, you need to fill the instance variables userInfoService and addressDetailsDao in the object on which you call the method. You might want to use mocks instead of the real classes, but that entirely depends on, what you want to verify.